# What is solution to Fatal error: Cannot use "self" when no class scope is active in avada theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, wampserver

I have freshly installed the Wordpress and then put the Avada theme files in the themes folder. When I attempted to install the Avada theme I get a fatal error:

> **Fatal error:** Cannot use "self" when no class scope is active in C:\xampp\htdocs\avada\wp-content\themes\Avada\framework\plugins\importer\importer.php on line 1000

I am running it **xampp server**. The WordPress version is **4.4.2**. I have searched a lot to find out what is the actual problems, But when I installed avada in the **wamp server**, it works fine. I want it in the xampp server for my personal tasks. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Edit file `/wp-content/themes/Avada/framework/plugins/importer/importer.php` on line 1000 
from : `self::deleteDir($file);`

to :`$this->deleteDir($file);`

Comment: looks like you were using php 7 :)

Comment: Hello I get the same error, I made the correction and I have not been solved.

Comment: Indeed, while passing From PHP5 to PHP7, self:: should be replaced by $this->